# cannot convert to 'System.Collections.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, list, collections

I have the following method in class `ProductSearch.cs` but I am getting error on line `PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result)`

> cannot convert from 'ProductSearch.ListOfProducts' to
>   'System.Collections.IEnumerable'

```
void service_GetObjectCompleted(object sender, GetObjectCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Count != 0)
    {
        PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result);
        pgrProductGrids.Source = pagingCollection;
        grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = pagingCollection;
    }
}
```

`e` contains an Object of class `ListOfProducts` which gets its value from this method present in `service.svn.cs` class

```
public ListOfProducts GetObject()
{
    ListOfProducts Listproducts = new ListOfProducts();
    ........
    using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Product product = new Product(reader["Name"].ToString(), reader["Code"].ToString());
            Listproducts.Product.Add(product);
        }
    }
    return Listproducts;
}
```

Here is the `ListOfProducts` class

```
public class ListOfProducts
{
    [DataMember()]
    public List<Product> Product { get; set; }

    public ListOfProducts()
    {
        Product = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously `e.Result` is of type `ListOfProducts` while the constructor of `PagedCollectionView` expects a `IEnumerable<ListOfProducts>`. But as long as you do not provide the code of `PagedCollectionView` and what `e.Result` is we can only guess.

Comment: What is `e.Result`? Does it has another members apart from `Count`? Use member which return list of objects, e.g. `e.Result.Items`.

Comment: A `List<Product>` property with the name `Product`? That seems wrong.

Comment: @Heinzi, why? `Product` and `ListOfProducts.Product` are valid names (disregarding meaning, I'd name property `Products` myself).

Comment: @Sinatr: Stuff being named improperly is often an indicator that the author misunderstood something on the conceptual level. The `ListOfProducts` class is *not* a list of products, it *contains* a list of products. This improper naming is (apparently) exactly what caused the OP's problem in the first place.

Comment: @Heinzi, I see, thought it is something I don't know ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try code below. Should works for your case

```
    PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result.Product);
```

And whole code

```
void service_GetObjectCompleted(object sender, GetObjectCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result.Count != 0)
    {
        PagedCollectionView pagingCollection = new PagedCollectionView(e.Result.Product);
        pgrProductGrids.Source = pagingCollection;
        grdProductGrid.ItemsSource = pagingCollection;
    }
}
```

Also u can use `indexer`

```
public Product this[int index]
{
      get { return Product[index]; }
      set { Product[index] = value; }
}
```